# How do I update votes from different radio buttons?

Tags: php, database, forms, radio-button

my teacher said that I have to use a for loop to show the names of the radiobuttons. It does that but it doesn't count the how many times a radio button is checked. So it doesn't submit the votes. This is for a school project. Here's the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['verzenden'])) {
$name= "item_" . $data2['id'];

for($name = item_0; $name <= item_28; $name++){
$query="UPDATE optie SET stemmen= stemmen + 1 WHERE id= '$name'";
if(mysql_query($query)){
echo"Stem opgeslagen! <br /><br/>";
} else {
echo"Fout tijdens opslaan stem!<br /><br/>";
} }}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poll");



while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo"<b>" . $data['vraag'] . "</b><br/><br />";

echo"<form method='post' action=''>";
echo "<fieldset>";

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM optie WHERE poll ='" . $data['id'] . "'");
while($data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){

echo "<input type='radio' name='item_" . $data2['id'] . "' value='" . $data2['id'] . "'/>" . $data2['optie'] . "<br />";
}

echo"<br/>";
echo"</fieldset>";
}
?>

</form>

<?php
```

I hope someone can help me,

bye Catherine

Comment: If you name the radio inputs as 'name="item[]"', you will end up with an array in $_POST which will be easier to work with. It gets rid of the for-loop around $name which is the source of your probelm.

Comment: I tried that, but then I can only select one radio button from only one question and not from the other questions

Comment: Then instead of naming them 'name="item[]"' you could name them after the question, Eg: name=" . $data['vraag'] .'[]".

Comment: Would that work? Because the questions have different radio buttons you can choose from

Comment: It's difficult to tell form the code you've given what will be the best solution for you. You seem to be in the initial learning stage so the best solution will be one that works and that you can understand how it works. I'm just coming up with ideas :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm learning it at school. I've changed the name into the I'd of the question. And it counts a vote of the radio button. Thnx for the suggestion :D

Answer (score 1):

This is the source of your problem:

```
for($name = item_0; $name <= item_28; $name++){
$query="UPDATE optie SET stemmen= stemmen + 1 WHERE id= '$name'";
```

The way you've specified it, `$name` can't be incremented. You need to use an integer like this:

```
for($name = 0; $name <= 28; $name++){
$query="UPDATE optie SET stemmen= stemmen + 1 WHERE id= 'item_$name'";
```

Comment: thnx! I changed it like that, but it still doesn't works. here's my code: if(isset($_POST['verzenden'])) {
$name= $data2['id'];

for($name = 0; $name <= 28; $name++){
$query="UPDATE optie SET stemmen= stemmen + 1 WHERE id= 'item_$name'";

if(mysql_query($query)){
echo"Stem opgeslagen! <br /><br/>";
} else {
echo"Fout tijdens opslaan stem!<br /><br/>";
} } }